# Socket.io + Express + Testing not working, but why?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

My server code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

function init() {
    server.listen(80, "0.0.0.0");
    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
    });
    app.use(express.static("public"));
}
```

Test file:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var io     = require('socket.io-client');
var SocketTester = require('socket-tester');

var app = require('../server');

var socketUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';

var options = {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    'force new connection': true
};

var socketTester = new SocketTester(io, socketUrl, options);

describe('Sockets', function () {
    var client1, client2, client3;
    it('should send and receive a message', function (done) {
        client1 = io.connect(socketUrl, options);
    });
});
```

The test file gives me an error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
    at listen (net.js:1267:10)
    at net.js:1376:9
    at node.js:933:3
```

How could I reach out to the server using the test file?

I'm not really sure what happens here:

```
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
```

But if I'm not mistaken this way the HTTP server only sees the socket.io, I guess the problem should be around here somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your port 80 is already in use by another application. Try to switch the node server to 3000 and then connect to it. Alternatively you can close the application listening on 80 - usually a webserver application.

In case it isn't clear, I'm referring to the following:

```
server.listen(3000); // There's no need to specify the host when you're running it on localhost.
```

Comment: The port is not being used I don't think that's the problem, if I change it to 3000 it still doesn't work. 
Check out the new error message:
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
    at listen (net.js:1267:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1363:5)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following code working for my app

I borrowed the port configuration from chai-http

I believe this code finds a port which is not in use

```
//During the test the env variable is set to test
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var User = require.main.require('models/User');

// https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#7-the-wrapper
var app = require.main.require('app');

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);


// From chai-http
function serverAddress (server, path) {
  if ('string' === typeof server) {
    return server + path;
  }
  var addr = server.address();
  if (!addr) {
    server.listen(0);
    addr = server.address();
  }
  var protocol = (server instanceof https.Server) ? 'https' : 'http';
  // If address is "unroutable" IPv4/6 address, then set to localhost
  if (addr.address === '0.0.0.0' || addr.address === '::') {
    addr.address = '127.0.0.1';
  }
  return protocol + '://' + addr.address + ':' + addr.port + path;
}

var socketURL = serverAddress(server,'/')

var options ={
  transports: ['websocket'],
  'force new connection': true
};


/**
 * Enable Socket.IO
 */
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

require('../../sockets')(io);

var ioClient = require('socket.io-client');


describe('Players Sockets', (done) => {

    var bonzo, magoo, fido;

    beforeEach((done) => { //Before each test we reset the database
      User.query().del().then(() => {
        var bonzoPromise = new User({name: 'bonzo', authtype: 'github', authid: '12345678'}).save();
        var magooPromise = new User({name: 'magoo', authtype: 'github', authid: '88345678'}).save();
        var fidoPromise = new User({name: 'fido', authtype: 'github', authid: '93231678'}).save();

        Promise.all([bonzoPromise,magooPromise,fidoPromise])
          .then((users)=>{
            bonzo = users[0];
            magoo = users[1];
            fido = users[2];
            done();
          })
      })
    });


  it('Should broadcast updated players when user disconnects', function(done){
    var clientFido = ioClient.connect(socketURL, options);

    clientFido.on('connect', function(data){
      clientFido.emit('whoami', { id: fido.id, name: fido.get('name') });

      var clientBonzo = ioClient.connect(socketURL, options);

      clientBonzo.on('connect', function(data){

        clientBonzo.emit('whoami', { id: bonzo.id, name: bonzo.get('name') });

        var clientMagoo = ioClient.connect(socketURL, options);

        clientMagoo.on('connect', function(data){
          clientMagoo.emit('whoami', { id: magoo.id, name: magoo.get('name') });

          clientMagoo.on('players', function(message){
            if(message.players.length < 3){ return; } // Ignore our own connect messages
            expect(message.players).to.be.a('array');
            expect(message.players.length).to.eq(3);
            expect(message.players.map((player)=>{ return player.name})).to.include.members([bonzo.get('name'), magoo.get('name'), fido.get('name')]);

            clientBonzo.on('players', function(message){
              expect(message.players).to.be.a('array');
              expect(message.players.length).to.eq(2);
              expect(message.players.map((player)=>{ return player.name})).to.include.members([bonzo.get('name'), fido.get('name')]);

              clientBonzo.disconnect();
              clientFido.disconnect();

              done();
            });

            clientMagoo.disconnect();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });

  it('Should broadcast updated players when user connects', function(done){
    var clientFido = ioClient.connect(socketURL, options);

    clientFido.on('connect', function(data){
      clientFido.emit('whoami', { id: fido.id, name: fido.get('name') });

      clientFido.on('players', function(message){
        expect(message.players).to.be.a('array');
        if(message.players.length == 1){ return; } // Ignore our own connect message
        expect(message.players.length).to.eq(2);
        expect(message.players.map((player)=>{ return player.name})).to.include.members([bonzo.get('name'), fido.get('name')]);

        clientBonzo.disconnect();
        clientFido.disconnect();
        done();
      });

      var clientBonzo = ioClient.connect(socketURL, options);
      clientBonzo.on('connect', function(data){
        clientBonzo.emit('whoami', { id: bonzo.id, name: bonzo.get('name') });
      });
    });
  });


});
```